# Javascript/FP/Reduce: Transforming a string based hierarchy to a nested object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reduce

(note to mods: this is not a duplicate of 'Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JSON objects' the problem being posed is somewhat different)

I need to transform a string based hierarchal representation of data to a nested javascript object representation.

I figure `lodash/collection/reduce` is could be useful. But what would be the best way to go about transforming / reducing a format like this;

```
{
 "a/b/c": 1,
 "a/b/d": 1,
 "e/f/g/h": 1,
 "e/f/g/i/j": 1
}
```

To something like this?

```
{ 
  "a": { 
    "b": { 
      "c": 1, 
      "d": 1 
    } 
  },
  "e": {
   "f": {
     "g": {
      "h": 1,
      "i": {
        "j": 1
      }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need Lodash just to get `.reduce()` - it's available in modern JavaScript environments on the Array prototype.

Comment: It you are willing to use ramda (http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/docs), mapObjectIndexed and assocPath will help.

Comment: @pointy actually I got the data structure slightly wrong, I need to operate on an object. Object.reduce is not available in modern JS afaik.  Updated example.

Comment: A good trick that often helps is to use `Object.keys()` to get the "own" property names of the object as an array, and then use `.reduce()` with that.

Comment: @MattRichards I might agree that this is not an exact duplicate, but "*I need to transform a string based hierarchal representation of data to a nested javascript object representation.*" is exactly the problem solved there. Can you be more specific please on *how* that linked post is not useful for you? What code do you have, what does not work? Are you insisting on using lodash methods?

Answer (score 2):

[**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with native javascript (sorry, not very familiar with lodash)

```js
var testObject = {
 "a/b/c": 1,
 "a/b/d": 1,
 "e/f/g/h": 1,
 "e/f/g/i/j": 1
};

var targetObject = {}

Object.keys(testObject).forEach(function(currentKey) {
  var currentValue = testObject[currentKey];
  currentKey.split('/').reduce(function(generatedObject, generatedKey, currentIndex, array) {
    if (!generatedObject[generatedKey]) {
      generatedObject[generatedKey] = {};
    }
    if (currentIndex == array.length - 1) {
      generatedObject[generatedKey] = currentValue;
    }
    return generatedObject[generatedKey];
  }, targetObject);
});

console.log(targetObject);
```

Comment: Hi AmmarCSE, thanks for the contribution. I got my example slightly wrong. I've corrected it above.

Comment: @MattRichards, check out my updated answer